# How to assign ip addresses contained in a Perl Variable, to a hash

Tags: perl, variables, hash

I have a variable that contains an IP Address, and the URL that goes with that IP Address, in a Perl variable called $holder.  I'm trying to populate a hash called `%HOSTNAMES`.  $holder contains:  `100.20.31.00, ThisBigSite-Fun`.  I've tried:

```
%HOSTNAME = $holder;
```

But it gives me the wrong key value pairs.  Is there a better way to assign a multiple value variable to a hash?

```
# lines contained a list of IP, URL-Addresses
my %HOSTNAME; 
foreach my $n (@lines) { 
  my $holder = (splice(@lines,0,1)); 
  %HOSTNAME = $holder;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code and not a (mostly) textual description of it? Which piece of your scalar is supposed to be the key? Which the value?

Comment: The value that's suppose to be the key is the IP with the value being the url.

Comment: @MikeAddison: How did you derive from the documentation that that is something that may work? You are creating a hash `%HOSTNAME` with one element that has a key of `100.20.31.00, ThisBigSite-Fun` and a value of `undef`. Strings don't spontaneously split into two. And please don't use Stack Overflow as a replacement for reading the language documentation and learning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple problems with your current approach:

```
my %HOSTNAME; 
foreach my $n (@lines) { 
  my $holder = (splice(@lines,0,1)); 
  %HOSTNAME = $holder;
}
```

1. no `use strict;` or `use warnings;`.
2. `$n` which holds the current element from the `@lines` array (the current line) is totally ignored. Instead on each iteration you cut the first element from `@lines` out and store it in `$holder`
3. the value of `%HOSTNAME` is overwritten on each iteration of the loop if you were to inspect `%HOSTNAME` after the loop completed it would only have a single entry (the last assigned entry)

A correct implementation would parse the IP address and Hostname from your string and then assign them (as different keys) into `%HOSTNAME`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %HOSTNAMES;
my @lines = (
  '100.20.31.00, ThisBigSite-Fun',
  '100.20.31.02, ThisBigSite-Fun2',
  '100.20.31.03, ThisBigSite-Fun3',
  '100.20.31.04, ThisBigSite-Fun4',
  '100.20.31.05, ThisBigSite-Fun5',
);

foreach my $line (@lines) {
  my ($ip, $host) = split /,\s*/, $line;

  $HOSTNAMES{$ip} = $host;
}

print Dumper \%HOSTNAMES;
#$VAR1 = {
#          '100.20.31.00' => 'ThisBigSite-Fun',
#          '100.20.31.03' => 'ThisBigSite-Fun3',
#          '100.20.31.05' => 'ThisBigSite-Fun5',
#          '100.20.31.02' => 'ThisBigSite-Fun2',
#          '100.20.31.04' => 'ThisBigSite-Fun4'
#        };
```

Comment: Excellent!  Works like a charm!  Thanks!

Comment: if the lines contain newlines, you may need to do `chomp @lines;`

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a string '100.20.31.00, ThisBigSite-Fun' and you want to turn it into a hash where the ip is the key and the hostname is the value it will look something like this:

```
my ($ip, $host) = split /,\s*/, $your_string;
$HOSTNAME{$ip} = $host
```

or if you want it the other way around

```
$HOSTNAME{$host} = $ip
```

note that while your hash is `%hostname` to access a key you need to use `$`

Comment: Excellent!  Worked like a charm!  Thanks!

Comment: Please don't prompt the asker to accept your answer. Let them decide themselves. I found it a good habit to wait a couple of hours or even days before marking an answer as _accepted_ for two reasons: a) questions without accepted answers usually attract more people, and b) perhaps other (better?) answers will then show up. @MikeAddison Refer to _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)_ and don't get in a hurry. (btw: this particular answer is correct, so I upvoted it.)

Comment: Don't take it personally. I learned the same way as @PerlDuck pointed out, but the explanation I got was much more terse and aggressive. He did a nice job of explaining why :)

Comment: Thank you, @stevieb but now I have bad conscience and feel a bit as if I'd stolen reputation from Nullman :-( Sorry. Also, I do not understand why someone downvoted this answer.

Comment: @PerlDuck dont worry about it, im not taking it personally or anything. im still new here and apparently made a faux pas, we live and learn

Comment: @PerlDuck Don't fret it. As I'm sure we all are aware, SO is not the easiest place to integrate into at first, so I just felt that your explanation was much more reasonable to explaining the situation than I've seen in the past. Keep up the good work.